# Is it possible to implement both a ListIterator and a Collection in java?

Tags: java, interface

So I have a class I have made which I wanted to be able to sort. To do so I simply had it implement the collection interface so it can be used in the Collections class.

Now I have noticed that the class itself is just a hop, skip, and a jump away from a ListIterator and it would be nice to have it implement that interface as well (looking into the future on this one). There is one problem, though, and that is that there is a method conflict between the Collection interface and ListIterator interface:

```
// from the Collection interface:
public boolean add(E someElement);

// from the ListIterator interface:
public void add(E someElement);
```

Is it possible to have one class conform to both interfaces? If not, does that mean that these two interfaces are mutually exclusive?

Comment: I'd first ask yourself why you feel like you need both.  If collection does what you need, why adding the extra requirement of ListIterator?  I always try not to over complicate code unless I have a functional reason to.

Comment: This will be a list group that I will use quite a bit in this job, and I can see in the future the possibility of needing a ListIterator out of it. The solution I created was to make a method that returned a ListIterator of the data. Not the most graceful solution, but a solution none-the-less...

Comment: Wouldn't it be good idea to extend the `AbstractList` class rather. You can take a look at `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` implementations and how they solve the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, they are mutually exclusive.

When you create an (abstract) class that tries to implement both, you'll get a compiler error.

> Main.java:16: error: types ListIterator and Collection are incompatible; both define add(java.lang.Object), but with unrelated return types
>   abstract class Foo implements Collection, ListIterator

Answer (score 4):

You are right, you can't implement both. But to be honest why do you want to do that?

If you need to expose a `ListIterator`, why don't you add a method that returns one?

`List` which extends `Collection` for instance doesn't extend `ListIterator` , it has a method called `listIterator` that returns the iterator.

```
ListIterator<E> listIterator();
```

Keep something in mind, a `Collection` is not an `Iterator`, a `Collection` is an `Iterable`.

Comment: And this is what I have ended up doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it is not possible to have both in a class.

But the semantics of a `ListIterator`, being an `Iterator`, forbids this nevertheless: a `Collection` is something you can iterate over as often as you want, while an `Iterator` is a one-shot thing which, once you have iterated over it, can be thrown away (or, in the case of a `ListIterator`, maybe rewound and re-used, but that's not the standard use case).